# Memoization: set the size of the consumed cache

Tags: python, caching, memoization

I am using memoization in order to speed up the utilization of a complex function `complexfunct()`.
This function takes as input a `numpy.array` of varying dimension (it can store from 5 to 15 values).
Each value of the `numpy.array` belongs to a set of 5 values.
So the number of allowed inputs for my `complexfunct()` is quite large, it is not possible to memoize all of them.
That is why when I run my jupyter notebook, it crashes.

The memoization funct I'm using is this one:

```
def memoize(func):
    """Store the results of the decorated function for fast lookup
    """
    # Store results in a dict that maps arguments to results
    cache = {}
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        key = str(args) + str(kwargs)
        if key not in cache:
            cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[key]
    return wrapper
```

My **question** is: can I set the size of the consumed cache, so that if it is saturated and a new input has to be store in the cache, then it will replace the first entry - or better, the least recently used.

Thank you all in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*if it is saturated and a new input has to be store in the cache, then it will replace the first entry - or better, the least recently used.*

Considering that you are caring about insertion order, when deciding what to remove I suggest using [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in place of `dict` i.e. add `import collections` and replace

```
cache = {}
```

using

```
cache = collections.OrderedDict()
```

then add check after insertion and if size is beyond limit just do:

```
cache.popitem(last=False)
```

to jettison oldest entry.

Comment: This may do the work for me.. thank you very much!